# Ejecutar dos SP con un solo Request?

Tags: array, nodejs, typescript, entity-framework, interface

gracias por tomarse el tiempo de ver mi consulta.

Estoy tratando de almacenar en mi DB en dos tablas diferentes. En la primera tabla se crea un solo registro, pero en la segunda son varios registros. Para darles contexto la siguiente foto:

[image: La informacion que va arriba de la tabla va para mi DB en la tabla Facturas , y la informacion que esta dentro de la tabla de la imagen (cantidad, descripcion)... esos van para mi DB en la tabla detalleFactura]

Estoy enviando todo en un payload que se ve algo asi:

```
{
    IDFactura:"1",
    FechaCreacion:"12/12/12",
    FechaLimite:"12/12/12",
    IDEmpleado:1,
    TipoFactura:1,
    IDCliente?:1,
    IDProveedor?:2
    DetalleFactura:[
        {
            IDProducto:1
             Cantidad: 2
        },
        {
            IDProducto:2
             Cantidad: 2
        },
        {
            {
            IDProducto:3
             Cantidad: 2
        }
    ]
}
```

en mi archivo de services estoy tratando de agarrar este payload en una funcion, dividir la informacion y mandar a llamar dos funciones, donde cada una de ellas ejecuta un SP que se encarga de llenar una tabla diferente:

```
public async nuevaFactura(req:Request, res:Response){
        const p:IFactura = req.body;
        this.crearFactura(p.IDFactura,p.FechaCreacion,p.FechaLimite,p.IDEmpleado, p.TipoFactura);
        this.detalleFactura(p.DetalleFactura);

    }

    public async crearFactura(IDFactura:number, FechaCreacion:string, FechaLimite:string, IDEmpleado:number, TipoFactura:number){

        const result : IResultado[] = await getConnection().query(`EXEC pFacturas.SP_CREATE_FACTURA
        @FechaCreacion = '${FechaCreacion}',
        @FechaLimite = '${FechaLimite}',
        @IDEmpleado = ${IDEmpleado},
        @TipoFactura =${TipoFactura},`);    
    }

    public async detalleFactura(detalleFactura:IDetalleFactura){

        detalleFactura.forEach(element => {

            const result : IResultado[]= await getConnection().query(`
                 EXEC pFacturas.CREATE_DETALLE_FACTURA
                 ${detalleFactura.Cantidad}//y para abajo lo que resta de informacion
                 ...
            `);
        });
    }
```

Estoy tratando de que en la funcion `detalleFactura()` crear un ciclo para que este llamando el SP hasta que terminen los datos que vienen en el arreglo de `DetalleFactura`.

No he logrado que funcione, alguno tiene una idea de como hacerlo? , estoy utilizando typeorm.

Gracias de Antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Asumo que **IDetalleFactura** tiene la siguiente estructura de 1 registro de DetalleFactura de tu payload:

```
export interface IDetalleFactura {
  IDProducto: number;
  Cantidad: number;
}
```

Si es así, entonces en la declaración de tu método debes indicar que se trata de un arreglo usando los [], así:

```
public async detalleFactura(detalleFactura: IDetalleFactura[]){
```

Incluso le podrías indicar que puede recibir un objeto o un arreglo:

```
public async detalleFactura(detalleFactura: IDetalleFactura | IDetalleFactura[]){
```

Si en tus SP solo mandas a guardar sin aplicar ninguna validación o tratamiento extra, entonces te recomiendo que definas las entidades e indiques la relación que existe entre ellas, y así solo mandar a guardar un objeto de tipo Factura con su arreglo de DetalleFactura:

```
await getRepository(Factura).save(factura);
```

- Factura es la clase que define la entidad
- factura es el objeto que se va a guardar

Saludos!

Cualquier cosa por acá andamos.